# Making a class callable in python

Tags: python

I came to know we can also make class as callable without implementing the `__call__()` function, and I am trying to write some thing like that but I got stuck:  below is my code

```
class neg:
    def __init__(self): # Classes are callables too
        self.val = 54545 
    def __repr__(self): 
        return str(self.val)

if __name__=='__main__':
       x=neg
       print(x) #print(neg()) also shows nothing
       #added by Merlin
       print('value of x:', x )
```

Executing the above does nothing, it doesn't print, What i am missing here?

The example i read to make class callable:

```
class Negate:
    def __init__(self, val): # Classes are callables too
    self.val = -val # But called for object, not work
    def __repr__(self): # Instance print format
    return str(self.val)
     actions = [square, sobject, pobject.method, Negate] # Call a class too
    for act in actions:
    print(act(5))
```

> I fixed the main it does work, but when they say a class are callable
>   then it shouldn't be `neg()` wasn't it?

Comment: The `__init__` method is an initializer. That's what happens when you create an instance of that class. It's in no way a "callable" in the traditional sense. Please read the docs, or tell us specifically what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "Executing the above does nothing, it doesn't print"  You must be doing something wrong, that exact code sample printed out `<class '__main__.neg'>` when I ran it.

Comment: Tadhg, i corrected the mistake as per the suggestion, didn't you saw my highlighted text?

Comment: try calling :  x=neg()

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the class to run the `__init__` method. And you also need to make sure your program starts up. You call/instantiate a function by writing `do_something()`; you call a class by writing `neg()`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__': # Fix the main so program starts
    x = neg() # Call the class!
    print(x)
```

Seeing that you commented that you need to "call" the class, have you tried experimenting with it? You should've gotten the answer. Look at a shell:

```
>>> neg
<class __main__.neg at 0x103842db8>
>>> neg()
5435                    # Displays the __repr__ return value.
```

Whether you're writing a function or a class, you don't need to implement `__call__` unless you're doing something complicated. Please, find some tutorials or read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are callable, only in the sense that you "call" a class to create an instance of the class. You call a class with the same syntax that you call functions, by using parenthesis and optional arguments. This is unrelated to *call*, which only affects instances.

Comment: @Explorer_N: I don't quite understand your comment. I don't know what you mean by "callable class".

Comment: Bryan, that is the first thing hits in my mind when i read the example(where they say classes are callable).. finally as everyone said they making object. then they shouldn't say classes are callable should they?

Comment: @Explorer_N: what example are you talking about? Who is "they"?

Comment: They Hmm Hopefully the person who brings the idea and written like classes are callable,the example I posted above.....

Comment: @Explorer_N: where did that example come from? Website? Book? Video? You are being very vague.

Comment: the example is from Book(learning python 5e),starts like....'Technically speaking, classes belong in the callable objects category too'pg no(1005)

Comment: @Explorer_N: you need to edit your question to include that information. You are misinterpreting what it says. Indeed, classes are callable. When you call them, they create instances.